# How do we show $\sup\{ks_n:n>N\}=k\sup\{s_n:n>N\}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

How do we show $\sup\{ks_n:n>N\}=k\sup\{s_n:n>N\}$?

I have hard time seeing the transition.

Comment: Is $k$ positive?

Comment: Is your k positive.

Comment: It must be positive, otherwise it would be the absolute value of $k$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just a hint**

Assume $k>0$.

Let $M=\sup A=\sup \{s_n : n>N\} $.

and $B=\{ks_n : n>N\} $.

we have
$$(\forall b\in B)\; \;\;b\le kM .$$

Given $\epsilon>0.$

$$(\exists a\in A) \;\;\; M-\epsilon/k <a\le M$$

$$\implies kM-\epsilon <ka\leq kM $$

$$(\exists b=ka\in B) \;\; \; kM-\epsilon <b\le kM $$
thus $kM=\sup B $.